# Need to Draw a Bar Graph ( in percentile manner ) in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

hi i have a data set like this

```
ALL  Critical Error Warning Review

2016 1412     475   4        125
154  45       49    2        58
116  86       12    1        17
```

I want to plot a stacked bar graph using ggplot2 where a single bar would show  100% of "ALL" and rest "Critical","Error","Warning","Review" should be on top of another according to their contribution in "ALL".

I am try it with no luck!!! Need a hand..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if your description of the desired plot is non-ambiguous.

My interpretation would  be the following:

```
## Copied from user1317221_G - Thanks for that.
babydf <- structure(list(ALL = c(2016L, 154L, 116L), Critical = c(1412L, 
45L, 86L), Error = c(475L, 49L, 12L), Warning = c(4L, 2L, 1L), 
    Review = c(125L, 58L, 17L)), .Names = c("ALL", "Critical", 
"Error", "Warning", "Review"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

# Add IDs
babydf <- cbind(id=1:nrow(babydf), babydf))

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# reshape the dataframe:
df.reshaped <- melt(babydf, id.vars='id')

ggplot(subset(df.reshaped, variable != 'ALL'), aes(x=id, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

If you want to have all bars of equal height, just do

```
babydf[, 3:6] <- babydf[, 3:6] / babydf$ALL * 100
```

before `melt`. The result:
[image]

Comment: thanks.. it worked to some extend. but i want a percentage in the y-axis not the counts. thanks

Comment: Hmm, and where exactly are counts on my second diagram? I always thought that all bars going to 100 should be something with percent.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice that..thank you so much. one more help would be much appreciated. actually actual data set is something like this.[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93667882/issue_data.csv. and i want to plot for each BU wise , Country Wise and Division Wise. I am having issues for prepossessing the data to suit the ggplot2 need. Help would be appreciated.@Thilo

Comment: As your new to StackOverflow, let me say some words of warning. Your question above was "downvoted" because you showed no effort of your own and you did describe your problem very vague. Usually, people here expect you to show of what you tried so far and explain where your problem is. We are all willing to help, but it is not about doing your work for you. My answer above was essentially to help you as a new user. Would you have had more than 50 reputation, I would have downvoted and left.

Comment: So, for your additional question (which might as well be a question of its own), I suggest the following: Ask a new question, provide a good sample dataset directly in R-code (see `?dput`) and describe what you did and where exactly your problem is. You could build up on the answer I provided above and show where the problem is with your extended dataset. I'm pretty sure that within a few minutes you will have a good quality answer and no downvotes, even an upvote might be possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask